# PHP contact form not sending email on submit

Tags: php, html, email

I've got a pretty straightforward form for my portfolio website but it's not sending emails to my inbox address.

Here's the HTML

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
        <label>Name <i class="fa fa-male"> </i> </label> <br />
        <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />

        <label>Email <i class="fa fa-envelope"> </i> </label> <br />
        <input type="email" name="email" /> <br />

        <label>Message <i class="fa fa-comment"> </i> </label> <br />
        <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message"></textarea> <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And the PHP

```
<?php
$myemail = 'danieldrave@live.com';

// GET THE CONTENT
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];

// BUILD THE MESSAGE
$to = $myemail;
$subject = "Client enquiry: $name";
$body = "$msg";

$headers = "From: $email";

// SEND EMAIL
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

// ACKNOWLEDGEMENT OF MESSAGE
header('Location: thankyou.php');
?>
```

For reference, the website does successful redirect to `thankyou.php`

Comment: Is the server configured to send out emails?

Comment: You should use real mail server. You can easily do that thru http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: What is the return value of the mail function ? (try printing it and commenting the redirection)

Comment: Just spend 10 min writing an anwser. and someone closed.....

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to look at:

1. Is your current hosting package able to / allowed to send emails ?
2. I have seen many cases where PHP mail function is not supported by Windows based hosting.
3. Put proper "Mail Header". For example, [look at this](http://rob.sun3.org/archives/107)
4. If above points are well matched, then check junk,spam folder.
5. You can opt for ready to use Mailer script - for example [look at this](http://phpmailer.worxware.com)

Comment: I've got an Ubuntu Droplet with Digital Ocean. How would I go about checking whether it can send mail from PHP contact forms?

Comment: Write a file and put <?php phpinfo(); ?> there and save. Then run that file from browser. 

Check for "mail", "sendmail" etc. If they are not empty, it should be fine.